# ng-disable not working in a radio button div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have a radio button div here that I would like to disable if `yAxisEditorCtrl.forceCombinedYAxis` is true.

Here's the code before my change

```
  <div class="y-axis-editor">
    <div class="vis-config-option display-size-normal form-group" ng-if=" yAxisEditorCtrl.supportsType()">
      <lk-vis-editor-radio-input label="Scale Type" model="yAxisEditorCtrl.type" options="yAxisEditorCtrl.typeOptions"/>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
```

Where the definition of `model` and `options` are:

```
  @type =
    value: null

  @typeOptions = [
    {name: "Linear", value: "linear"}
    {name: "Logarithmic", value: "log"}
  ]
```

So I tried to add `ng-disabled="yAxisEditorCtrl.forceCombinedYAxis"` to my div like this:

```
  <div class="y-axis-editor">
    <div class="vis-config-option display-size-normal form-group" ng-if=" yAxisEditorCtrl.supportsType()" ng-disabled="yAxisEditorCtrl.forceCombinedYAxis">
      <lk-vis-editor-radio-input label="Scale Type" model="yAxisEditorCtrl.type" options="yAxisEditorCtrl.typeOptions"/>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
```

However, even with `ng-disabled` to true (I checked the output), it still won't disable.

[image]

I even tried adding it within the div where the radio button is defined, but still not disabled.

Curious how I could get this to work?

Comment: It says `true` or `false`, which is what I expected. No errors.

Comment: Nope, removing the `ng-if` does not work.

Comment: Even if I set it to `ng-disabled="true"` it doesn't work. So I'm pretty confused

Comment: Two quick things: (1) `disabled` on the `div` will _not_ do anything.... and, (2) I just realized that you're using some sort of directive for the input, _not_ a standard HTML input.  Change the input to `<input type="radio"....`> and test that.  _Then_, you need to share with us which library you are using that contains the `lk-vis-editor-radio-input` directive... **The trick to troubleshooting things like this** is to start simple, then add complexity.  So move that `ng-disabled` to the input, and change the input to a standard input.... then, do the research on `lk-vis-editor-radio-input`

Answer (score 0):

`ng-disabled` is for *inputs*, it appears you inadvertently put it on the `div`.

Here's the corrected code:

```
  <div class="y-axis-editor">
    <div class="vis-config-option display-size-normal form-group" ng-if="yAxisEditorCtrl.supportsType()">
      <lk-vis-editor-radio-input label="Scale Type" ng-disabled="yAxisEditorCtrl.forceCombinedYAxis" />
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
```

As a `div` is not interactive, it cannot be disabled.  If you want it to have a particular appearance or styling, I'd recommend using `ng-class` to conditionally add the "disabled" appearing class to the `div`

Comment: Hm, that still did not work. I am wondering if it's because of some missing information I thought wasn't necessary in the question. I'm going to update my div with all my code, in particular, adding in the `model` and `options`

Comment: Hi cale_b, I've updated the code hoping to shine some more light to this issue.